# ASP.Net Core React.js Template Azure AD Authentication & Authorization

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, azure-active-directory, asp-net-core-spa-services

I have set my `Startup.cs` as per these [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/scenario-web-app-sign-user-app-configuration?tabs=aspnetcore).

The thing is that my SPA is located at `https://localhost:5000` and my API is located at `https://localhost:5000/api`. When I access the SPA URL I get some errors, but if I go to the API URL, then I'm redirected to the `https://login.microsoftonline.com/...rest` where I can perform the login. After that, I get a cookie set, then my SPA application works.

My question is the following, how can I access the SignIn/SignOut functionalities at will. From these [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/scenario-web-app-sign-user-sign-in?tabs=aspnetcore) I see that there is an Account controller which can be accessed. But I tried navigating to it by "guessing" the URL and I didn't manage to do so.

I see that the controller's functionalities can be accessed by defining some Razor pages, e.g.:

```
<ul class="navbar-nav">
  @if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
  {
    <li class="nav-item">
        <span class="navbar-text text-dark">Hello @User.Identity.Name!</span>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link text-dark" asp-area="MicrosoftIdentity" asp-controller="Account" asp-action="SignOut">Sign out</a>
    </li>
  }
  else
  {
    <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link text-dark" asp-area="MicrosoftIdentity" asp-controller="Account" asp-action="SignIn">Sign in</a>
    </li>
  }
</ul>
```

How can I do this from React? I'm not sure that I follow the appropriate docs.

Comment: In a SPA, you need to use "@azure/msal-browser" library, or in fact in your case "@azure/msal-react" to authenticate. The back-end should be configured for JWT authentication. With MS.Identity.Web, you'd use `AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApi` instead of the Web App one. It looks like you are configuring the back-end for interactive authentication, but it should not be doing that. The front-end needs to handle the interactions.

Comment: That's what I was feeling too. But I had some dilemmas of having Application related GUIDs and the TenantId on the FrontendSide. I think I will follow [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/quickstart-v2-javascript-auth-code-react) piece of documentation.

Comment: Yeah that documentation looks good. The client id and tenant id are not secrets :)

Comment: I managed to access the graph api from my spa app, but when I try to make requests to my custom API, the calls fail. I followed this [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/quickstart-v2-aspnet-core-web-api) and the requests still fail.

Comment: You need a different `scope` to get a token for your API. A token for MS Graph won't work for your back-end.

Comment: I see, but after adding another scope, then I cannot login, getting this error: `ServerError: invalid_client: someId: The application 'MyApp' asked for scope 'access_as_user' that doesn't exist on the resource '00000003-0000-0000-c000-000000000000'`. Contact the app vendor.` So for some reason it is asking for a graph token.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/236678/discussion-between-vivere-and-juunas).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone landing here and being a bit confused as I was here is what docs I followed to set this up:

1. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/quickstart-v2-aspnet-core-web-api
2. https://github.com/Azure-Samples/ms-identity-javascript-react-tutorial/tree/main/3-Authorization-II/1-call-api (provided by @juunas).

Also read the comments for more info.